# rails rspec capybara testing Capybara::ElementNotFound:Unable to find field "title"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

No idea why is it doing so the otherone passed this doesent

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Editing tickets" do
    let!(:project) {FactoryGirl.create(:project)}
    let!(:ticket) {FactoryGirl.create(:ticket, project: project)}

    before do
        visit '/'
        click_link project.name
        click_link ticket.title
        click_link "Edit Ticket"
    end

    scenario "Updating a ticket" do
        fill_in "Title", with: "Make it really shiny!"
        click_button "Update Ticket"

        expect(page).to have_content "Ticket has been updated."

        within("#ticket h2") do
            expect(page).to have_content("Make it really shiny!")
        end

        expect(page).to_not have_content ticket.title
    end

    scenario "Updating a ticket with invalid information" do
        fill_in "Title", with: ""
        click_button "Update Ticket"

        expect(page).to have_content("Ticket has not been updated.")
    end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@project, @ticket] do |f| %>
<% if @ticket.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@ticket.errors.count, "error") %>
            prohibited this ticket from being saved.</h2>

            <ul>
                <% @ticket.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <% end %>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :title , "Title" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :description, "Description" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </p>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

Ticket's controller

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_project
    before_action :set_ticket, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def new
        @ticket = @project.tickets.build
    end

    def create
        @ticket = @project.tickets.build(ticket_params)
        if @ticket.save
            flash[:notice] = "Ticket has been created."
            redirect_to [@project, @ticket]
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Ticket has not been created."
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private

    def ticket_params
        params.require(:ticket).permit(:title, :description)
    end

    private

    def set_project
        @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    private

    def set_ticket
        @ticket = @project.tickets.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

show.html.erb from project's view's

```
<% title(@project.name, "Projects") %>
<h2><%= @project.name %></h2>
<%= link_to "Edit Project", edit_project_path(@project) %>
<%= link_to "Delete Project", project_path(@project),
            method: :delete,
            data: {confirm:
                    "Are you sure you want to delete this project?"
                    } %>
<%= link_to "New Ticket", new_project_ticket_path(@project) %>

<ul id="tickets">
    <% @project.tickets.each do |ticket| %>
    <li>
        #<%= ticket.id %> -
        <%= link_to ticket.title, [@project, ticket] %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Tickets show.html.erb

```
<div id="ticket">
    <h2><%= @ticket.title %></h2>
    <%= link_to "Edit Ticket", [:edit, @project, @ticket] %>
    <%= simple_format(@ticket.description) %>
</div>
```

And the error is

> 1) Editing tickets Updating a ticket
>        Failure/Error: fill_in "title", with: "Make it really shiny!"
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find field "title"
>        # ./spec/features/editing_tickets_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> 2) Editing tickets Updating a ticket with invalid information
>        Failure/Error: fill_in "Title", with: ""
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find field "Title"
>        # ./spec/features/editing_tickets_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in '

Comment: Use 2 spaces for indenting your Ruby code, not 4 (or Tab)

Answer (score 1):

After your edit form submits, the user is not redirected to the `show.html.erb` page. That is why the assertion is failing.

Add an edit action that on sucess renders your show page.

```
render :show
```

Comment: sorry this was my mistake i forgot to add a additional page from project's view's which contains the #ticket.

Comment: and no the ("Ticket has not been updated.") is not displayed because i havent gotten to add the update button feature.

Comment: When you update a ticket, are you sure you go to the 'show' page? I'm not seeing that logic in the controller.

Comment: uhh these long coding hour's are affecting me hard i added the show html from the ticket's view file it should help you understand the error better i suppose..